# canvas size is different when drawing canvas size

Tags: vue.js, canvas

Could you tell me how to fix this issue: canvas has 1200x700px, but the drawing is scaled to 300x150?

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="msg"></input>
        <br>
        <canvas v-on:mousemove="mouse" id="c"></canvas>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
                vueCanvas: null,
                pixel: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            mouse: function (event) {
                this.vueCanvas.putImageData(this.pixel, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)
                this.msg = event.offsetX + ":" + event.offsetY

            },
            init: function () {
                this.vueCanvas = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
                this.pixel = this.vueCanvas.createImageData(1, 1);
                this.pixel.data[3] = 255;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.init()

        }


    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    #c {
        height: 700px;
        width: 1200px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
</style>
```

Snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      vueCanvas: null,
      pixel: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    mouse: function(event) {
      this.vueCanvas.putImageData(this.pixel, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      this.msg = event.offsetX + ':' + event.offsetY;
    },
    init: function() {
      this.vueCanvas = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
      this.pixel = this.vueCanvas.createImageData(1, 1);
      this.pixel.data[3] = 255;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
})
```

```css
#c {
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="msg" />
  <br />
  <canvas v-on:mousemove="mouse" id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

I have recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0W49vTuXiA&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=Bart%C5%82omiejBartnicki) in order to show what goes wrong.

Comment: Try setting it on the element itself: `<canvas v-on:mousemove="mouse" id="c" height="700" width="1200"></canvas>`

Comment: it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I find solution:

```
this.vueCanvas.canvas.width=this.vueCanvas.canvas.clientWidth //300->1200
this.vueCanvas.canvas.height=this.vueCanvas.canvas.clientHeight //150->700
```

but I am not sure if is it good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I meant in my comment:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      vueCanvas: null,
      pixel: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    mouse: function(event) {
      this.vueCanvas.putImageData(this.pixel, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      this.msg = event.offsetX + ':' + event.offsetY;
    },
    init: function() {
      this.vueCanvas = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
      this.pixel = this.vueCanvas.createImageData(1, 1);
      this.pixel.data[3] = 255;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
})
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="msg" />
  <br />
  <canvas v-on:mousemove="mouse" id="c" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>
</div>
```

Is this not how you want it?